Request token names for millions of addresses in a dataset
I am making a dashboard with data about ethereum tokens and I need to extract token name for each smart contract in the database. But I have over 10 millions of records and I have found that etherscan limits the number of api requests per day and slows down the rate of requests. Are there smart contract services that allow api requests for big data at a reasonable rate?

Etherscan, Moralis, Chainnodes and other web3 providers have paid plans that allow more requests. You could start testing with a couple of them that offer a free tier then decide depending which one work best for your particular use case.
